# what means the use of a Triplestore

Tags: database, rdf, triplestore

the use of a triplestore means that we are going to use a database that have a table with 3 coluns and 7 indexes?
I mean using a triple store always is relationed with that relational model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triplestore:

> A triplestore is a purpose-built database for the storage and retrieval of Resource Description Framework (RDF) metadata.

It looks like that the high-performance triplestores use a non-relational model:

> Some triplestores have been built as database engines from scratch, while others have been built on top of existing commercial relational database engines (i.e. SQL-based).<sup>[4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triplestore#cite_note-3)</sup> Like the early development of OLAP databases, this intermediate approach allowed large and powerful database engines to be constructed for little programming effort in the initial phases of triplestore development. Long-term though it seems likely that native triplestores will have the advantage for performance. A difficulty with implementing triplestores over SQL is that although "triples" may thus be "stored", implementing efficient querying of a graph-based RDF model (i.e. mapping from SPARQL) onto SQL queries is difficult.<sup>[5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triplestore#cite_note-4)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily. There are triplestores that rely on other RDBMS systems as backends. Examples of this case are: Jena/SDB, 3store or Virtuoso.

Others implement their own native persistent model customized to respond better to the RDF data model, like 4store, Jena/TDB or BigData. These tend to scale better.

Answer (score 0):

*Conceptually*, yes - a triple is a binary relation with a subject, predicate, and object (e.g. <JohnSmith--marriedTo->JillSmith>.

Higher arity relations are not possible in a triple store as they are in a normal RDBMS (though you can fake them via the use of multiple triples).

The *implementation* varies though, as previous answers state.

Most triple stores actually store quads, so they can group triples into subsets ("Named Graphs" in RDF-speak).

The indexes are of course optional, but usually present in some form - again often modified to accommodate quads.